# how to disconnect asus usb connection from eclipse

Tags: applications, security, usb-connection-mode, android-sdk, asus-zenfone-5

im a beginner in android apps mobile. i already launch it in my phone asus T00Q, but i have problem to disconnect the usb from eclipse. some said we should put the mode on charging mode and not Media device(MTP) mode, bcause it will corrupt the sd card. the phone showing its charging. but i cannot change it in charging mode as the only option is Media device (MTP) and camera (PTP). how can i disconnect it properly from eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Modern devices and especially devices with their own power supply are not harmed if you simply unplug the USB cable.
Most storage controllers have enough power left even if the device shuts down to flush the read/write cache and prevent any corruption.